# Nuxt3 - useFetch() not works on event click, works on onMounted()

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I am trying to delete an element from client side. I am using script setup and on onMounted hook the request works fine, but when i try to run the same code on event click, it throws me an error

```
onMounted(() => {
 const { data, pending, error, refresh } = await useFetch(
   'https://example.com/api/api-request',
   {
      method: 'DELETE',
   }
 )
})
```

on clcik event throws an error

```
const testDelete = async() => {
  const { data, pending, error, refresh } = await useFetch(
    'https://example.com/api/api-request',
    {
      method: 'DELETE',
      headers: {
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*"
      },
    }
  )
}
```

Access to fetch at 'https://example.com/api/api-request' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Method DELETE is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.

https://example.com/api/api-request is just example, with Postman request works fine and element is deleted.

Comment: This solved the problem. On the backend side.

header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD, PATCH");

Comment: Let s inspect the CORS policy of your system, and check if it s caused by your root url : try http:// , http://www.  to call your script